# Capybara, Cucumber, GWT problem asserting the text with inline styles

Tags: gwt, cucumber, capybara

I was to check to see if a text with inline styles exist.

For example `page.should have_content(text)` works for raw text such as

`"Time out"`,

however it does not work for the text

`"Time out. Please <a href=#">Click</a> here to retry".`

Also I have been having trouble trying to locate an anchor with inline style as well ex:

`<a>click <strong>here</strong>to retry</a>`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that have_content tests for text, not markup.  You can do this though:

```
page.body.should include('... <a>...</a> ...')
```

Regarding your second question, I don't think it's possible to do `page.has_link?` with markup.  You would have to construct your own XPath expression and then use `page.should have_selector(:xpath, '...')`.  Or test for the raw HTML using `page.body` of course.